# Retrieving a picture for a given photo type is not behaving consistently

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I tried
https://graph.facebook.com/object_id/picture
and
https://graph.facebook.com/object_id/picture?type=normal
to get a bigger size photo. I'm only getting some of them while the others just returned question marks. Does anyone knows how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the object. For example, if you want to get the picture of a page that is restricted to some countries, or restricted to a minimum age, it will not work that easily. In that case, you would need a user access token, otherwise Facebook does not know which user tries to get the picture, or if he even got a Facebook account. Those links can also be called by CURL or file_get_content in an external website, for example.

Also, some users restrict general access to apps, could also be a reason why you only get question marks.

For further investigation, it would be interesting to get some examples, of course.

Comment: Even if it's user uploaded photo (not apps), it doesn't work sometimes. (type="photo", status_type="added_photo") I was checking with this feed, I can click into the object_id and see different dimensions of the photo in the image object. But when I try to load it, I only get question mark.

Comment: some calls also need an access token to work, and there are 3 of them (app access token, user access token, page access token). the app access token is the only one that you get without user login, it´s just "APP-ID|APP-SECRET".

Answer (score 0):

I realized that if I have access token in the url, it will work.

Comment: Actually, it's still not guaranteed that I'll get the photos even if I  added the access token in the url.